# Heatmap incorporating icons

Tags: r, heatmap

everyone! I have a dataset that looks like the below:

```
Person    Points   Day1  Day2 ...  Dayx
Craig     102     -0.1   0.2  ...  1
Jeff      42      -0.1   1    ...  0.1
Steph     307      0.1   0.2  ... -0.1
```

Basically, **Person** is a string, while **Points**, **Day1**, **Day2** etc are numbers (x>50). I am reading this in from an Excel file.

Like many datasets, higher numbers are important, and I want them to stand out.

I would like to plot **Person** against **Day1**, **Day2**... **Dayx**. This would ideally look like a heatmap ([example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050803/plot-discrete-data), [example 2](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/)), but I would like to have dots of different colours instead of cells of different shades. I have not been able to achieve this using dotplots. ggplots get close, but I cannot seem to control the size of the dots.

Also, I would like all instances of negative **Dayx** values to be replaced with an icon instead of a dot. Similarly, also want to force all instances of a certain value (0.1) in all the **Dayx** variables to be replaced with a different icon or dot configuration. (there are a lot of 0.1s in my dataset which are not so important).
Please let me know how you would go about this in R studio. While I have fooled around with ggplot several times, please note that I would not consider myself an advanced user.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What library are you using? Can you add the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with some dummy data.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  Person = c('Craig', 'Jeff', 'Steph'),
  Day1 = runif(3),
  Day2 = c(-1, runif(2)),
  Day3 = runif(3),
  Day4 = c(runif(2), -1),
  Day5 = runif(3),
  Day6 = runif(3)
)
```

The dots can be created with `geom_point` and the images can be created with `geom_image`. Set the negative values to `NA` and use `scale_color_continuous(na.value = "transparent")` to hide the points.

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Person) %>%
  mutate(
    value = ifelse(value < 0, NA, value),
    image = ifelse(is.na(value), "https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png", NA)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Person, x = name, col = value, image = image)) +
  geom_point(size = 35) +
  scale_color_continuous(na.value = "transparent") +
  ggimage::geom_image(aes(image = image), size = 0.15, color = "red") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Paul, this seems like an ideal solution. But the pipe function does not seem to be working. I keep getting the following error:
Error in df %>% pivot_longer(-Person) %>% mutate(value = ifelse(value <  : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: It looks like `tidyverse` isn't loaded. Can you run `install.packages("tidyverse")` and `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks Paul!